# How to keep any program on Windows Startup with batch command

Tags: batch-file, startup

I want to run batch file on windows startup working with Windows 7, Windows 8 or Windows 8.1 which will start automatically on Windows Startup from any location of PC so that whenever PC start it will run automatically. Is there have any way to do that ?

Comment: probably there are better ways to do what you would like to achieve. what does the batch file start? a particular program ?

Answer (score 1):

you can use the task scheduler for that,

```
Action: Start a program
Program/script: path to your batch file : "c:\my\batch.bat"
Add arguments (optional): add here start parameters
Start in parameter (optional): Fullpath of your bat file location (needed if librarys are attached)
```

alternatively there is `C:\Windows\System32\gpedit.msc`

[image: run program\script on logon]

There you can easily navigate to adminstrative templates --> logon and add your script

Answer (score 0):

A third method (and possibly the easiest) is to copy your files into the GP machine scripts startup folder.

```
C:\Windows\System32\GroupPolicy\Machine\Scripts\Startup
C:\Windows\System32\GroupPolicy\Machine\Scripts\Shutdown
```

Also works from the $OEM$ folder in case any readers are doing fresh installations.